# how to install libnice on its master branch

Tags: 18.04

i am trying to install and compile the libnice library i am trying to install janus server
i am following the same procedure as given in the docs

> While libnice is typically available in most distros as a package, the
> version available out of the box in Ubuntu is known to cause problems.
> As such, we always recommend manually compiling and installing the
> master version of libnice. Installation of libnice master is quite
> straightforward:

```
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libnice/libnice
cd libnice
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && sudo make install
```

i got  following errors when executing these commands

```
myuser:~/libnice$./autogen.sh
bash: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory

myuser:~/libnice$ ./configure --prefix=/usr

bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

myuser:~/libnice$ make && sudo make install
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

these are the contents of libnice folder

```
.   agent    build    COPYING.LGPL  docs      .git        .gitlab-ci.yml  meson.build        NEWS  random  socket  subprojects  TODO
..  AUTHORS  COPYING  COPYING.MPL   examples  .gitignore  gst             meson_options.txt  nice  README  stun    tests
```

how can i resolve this issue
i am using ubuntu 18.04 lts

Comment: According to the repo's `README` file, *"libnice uses the Meson Build System..."* - did you try following the instructions given there?

Answer (score 1):

just note to others:

the asker is following the old instructions for libnice 0.1.16 and before
starting from 0.1.17, they use meson to build. you also need ninja iirc.
the instructions in janus above are given in older readmes for older versions of janus.

when trying to follow that on ubuntu 18.04 (I need that older version of janus, and am trying to use libnice 0.1.16 as listed in that readme of janus, though newer version should work... but gave me a different error...), I had to jump through a bunch of hoops to install:

should be:

```
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libnice/libnice
cd libnice
git checkout 5969b34e3acd9150506ed8d9d109c73665858f3e
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && sudo make install
```

but autogen.sh fails, because no aclocal
so, looking that up, we see mention of [solving this](https://kerneltalks.com/troubleshooting/how-to-resolve-aclocal-not-found-error-in-ubuntu/) in general with
sudo apt install autotools-dv
sudo apt install automake
and then running again
now we get a failure from autogen because of no gtkdocize. A google mentions downloading gtk-doc-tools to solve this.
sudo apt install gtk-doc-tools
and that gets us to a failure because of no LIBTOOL

```
Makefile.am: installing './INSTALL'
agent/Makefile.am:31: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
```

so
sudo apt install libtool
new error,

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.48 gio-2.0 >= 2.48 gobject-2.0 >= 2.48 gthread-2.0) were not met:

No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'gio-2.0' found
No package 'gobject-2.0' found
No package 'gthread-2.0' found
```

so,
sudo apt install glib-2.0
(already installed it seems) sudo apt install gio-2.0
(already installed it seems) sudo apt install gobject-2.0
(this doesn't exist, so do the next line) sudo apt install gthread-2.0
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev
try one more time.... and voila? Seems to work? we'll see...

`./configure --prefix=/usr`
`make && sudo make install`

but I find myself unsure as to whether I have a local version of libnice installed that needs to be removed... pretty sure I don't, but 0.1.14-1 of libnice-dev is listed in repos.